# delete an array from localStorage vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have a problem, when I delete my array from localStorage it works, but when I add a new option the previous option reappears. I am using localStorage.removeItem('arrayOption') , how to permanently delete it ? thank you for help

```
<template>
   <div v-for="option in arrayOption" :key="option.id_option">
           
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>{{ option.name}} </p>
                    <p>{{ option.description}}</p>
                </div>
                <div  >
                   
                        <button  @click="deleteOption(option.id_option)" >-</button>
                        <p v-if="option.count == 0">{{ count }}</p>
                        <p v-else>{{ option.count }}</p>
                       <button @click=" addOption(option.id_option)">+</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      arrayOption: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'option1',
          description: 'je suis l option 1 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'option2',
          description: 'je suis l option 2 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'option3',
          description: 'je suis l option 3 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'option4',
          description: 'je suis l option 4 ajoute moi au panier'
        }
      ],
      testCount: {},
    }
  },
   methods:{
    deleteOption(){
        localStorage.removeItem('arrayOption')
    },
     addOption(id){
        let addArrays = this.arrayOption[id]
        localStorage.setItem("arrayOption",JSON.stringify(addArrays))
    },
}
```

Comment: Where's `addOption` method?

Comment: I added addOption @Areg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're picking up an index from array instead of finding the array item with selected id. Try to change this

```
addOption(id){
  const selectedArray = this.arrayOption.find(i => i.id === id)
  localStorage.setItem("arrayOption",JSON.stringify(selectedArray))
}
```

Comment: @tony cool, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer in case of other people will have trouble with something similar like this too

Comment: I don't know how to do this to mark it's the correct answer @Areg

Comment: @tony press the check mark under the vote buttons